# Xampp: Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, xampp, web-development-server

I recently downloaded xampp but apache isn't running. I tried to change ports ( 80 to 81,8080 and 443 to 4433,4430 ), opened new ports (80, 443) but the result is same.

Comment: What version did you download? Onto what operating system?

Comment: I found the solution. I just installed C++ distributor and it worked. You can find it here. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170    . If it didn't work, go to apache > logs > apache(error.log). Copy paste the error on google and pretty sure you will get a solution. Mine was  (PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.